Can I degrade Groundclear with vinegar
Sprayed groundclear in a place where I want to plant.  Can I degrade groundclear with a high concentration of vinegar, then follow it with lime?

Groundclear is glyphosphate and for long term Imazapyr. The second one is already an acid: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Imazapyr. It seems water and sun (and hot weather) should decompose it quickly. Try it, and move soil so also other soil will get sun. In any case I would also remove the soil and put new soil (you can recycle the old soil later).

Checking the product label for Groundclear, we see Glyphosate and Imazapyr are the villains.
Active Ingredients
Glyphosate, isopropylamine salt.....5.00%
Imazapyr, isopropylamine salt.......0.08%
Other Ingredients..................94.92%
Total.............................100.00%

Looking at Glyphosphate

Glyphosate degradation is a mainly microbial-mediated process [29,30],
and the pathway has been widely studied in laboratories [31]. It
degrades at a relatively rapid rate in most soils, with half-life
estimated between 7 and 60 days [12].

Looking at Imazapyr

The half-life of imazapyr in soil ranges from one to five months.


Because imazapyr is a weak acid herbicide, environmental pH will
determine its chemical structure, which in turn determines its
environmental persistence and mobility. Below pH 5 the adsorption
capacity of imazapyr increases and limits its movement in soil. Above
pH 5, greater concentrations of imazapyr become negatively charged,
fail to bind tightly with soils, and remain available (for plant
uptake and/or microbial breakdown). In soils imazapyr is degraded
primarily by microbial metabolism. It is not, however, degraded
significantly by photolysis or other chemical reactions. The half-life
of imazapyr in soil ranges from one to five months.

The imazapyr will outlast the glyphosphate, and imazapyr degrades more slowly in acidic environments.  So no, vinegar will lower the pH and not help you.  If the soil pH is already below 5, raising it above 5 with lime will help accelerate the degradation.
Also keep in mind that these times are half-lives.  The poison is still in the soil, just in ever-dwindling-never-gone amounts.  There won't be a clear cutoff for 'gone', just a vague point of 'gone enough'.
